# FluentValidation DI Passing Values to Child Validators

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, fluentvalidation

I recently discovered FluentValidator and started to play around with dependency injection. I can't seem to figure out how to pass a value to a child validator using the current DI setup.

I'd like to access Invoice.InvoiceNumber from the InvoiceDetailsValidator.

```
public class InvoiceValidator : AbstractValidator<Invoice>
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<DbContext> dbContextFactory;

    public InvoiceValidator(InvoiceDetailsValidator invoiceDetailsValidator, IDbContextFactory<DbContext> dbContextFactory)
    {
        ...

        RuleFor(x => x.InvoiceNumber)
            .Must(BeSomething)
            .WithMessage("Invoice number is required.");

        RuleForEach(x => x.InvoiceDetails)
            .SetValidator(invoiceDetailsValidator);
    }
}
```

```
public class InvoiceDetailsValidator : AbstractValidator<InvoiceDetails>
{
    public InvoiceDetailsValidator(IDbContextFactory<DbContext> dbContextFactory)
    {
        ...

        RuleFor(x => x.InvoiceSection)
            .NotEmpty()
            .When(X => !string.IsNullOrEmpty( /* InvoiceNumber? */ ))
            .WithMessage("Invoice section is required.");
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change Paarent validator constructor from

```
    public InvoiceValidator(InvoiceDetailsValidator invoiceDetailsValidator, 
                            IDbContextFactory<DbContext> dbContextFactory
                           )
```

to

```
    public InvoiceValidator(IValidator<InvoiceDetails> invoiceDetailsValidator, 
                            IDbContextFactory<DbContext> dbContextFactory
                           )
```

Comment: This still doesn't answer how Invoice.InvoiceNumber could be passed down to the child validator. The validation depends on a property from the parent class